# Hole in number is printing the size of the array

Tags: java, arrays

I have taken a number as an input. Converted that number into an array. 
I want to count the number of holes in the integers of an array and print the number. However this code is just printing me the length of the array. I am not able to identify the mistake.

```
 public static void holesinNum(int num){
    int numofholes = 0;
    int[] numarr = new int[String.valueOf(num).length()]; //converting a number to array
    //int len = numarr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i<numarr.length; i++){
        if(numarr[i]==8)
        {
            numofholes +=2;
        }   
        else if(numarr[i]==0 || numarr[i]==6 || numarr[i]==9)
        {
            numofholes++;   
        }
    }
//return numofholes;
    System.out.println("Total holes in int are: " +numofholes);
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    FindholesinNum.holesinNum(num);
}

}

  Output:
     Enter a number: 
     8476201
     Total holes in int are: 7
     It should actually be: 4. 7 is just length of the array
```

Comment: You create `numarr` but don't put any data in it.

Comment: ... and the default value of an `int` is zero, so `numarr` is currently always an array of length `num` filled with zeros.

Comment: I have passed the int num from main. It is showing me the correct length of the array so it is not null.  I get the output as Enter a number: 
6984
Total holes in int are: 4

Comment: Provide some sample output (some `num`s, and what should they produce)

Comment: Enter a number: 
6984
Total holes in int are: 4 should be the number of holes. As 6 and 9 have one 'hole' 8 has 2 'holes'

Comment: @Learner_me Debugging tip: In the `for` loop add: `System.out.println(numarr[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an array for that:

```
public static int holesInNum(int num){
  int holes = 0;
  while(num > 0){
    switch(num % 10){
      case 0:
      case 6:
      case 9:
        holes++;
        break;
      case 8:
        holes +=  2;
        break;
    }
    num /= 10;
  }
  return holes;
}
```

Where `num % 10` is the remainder of `num`, when it is divided by `10`. Try it separately if it is not known yet.

---

Even if you wanted a `for` loop, still you would not use an array, but loop over the characters in `String.valueOf(num)`:

```
public static int holesInNum(int num){
  int holes = 0;
  String s = String.valueOf(num);
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    switch(s.charAt(i)){
      case '0':
      case '6':
      case '9':
        holes++;
        break;
      case '8':
        holes += 2;
        break;
    }
  return holes;
}
```

Of course `if`-s can be used in place of the `switch`, that part was completely fine in your attempt too:

```
char c=s.charAt(i);
if(c=='8')
  holes+=2;
else if(c=='0' || c=='6' || c=='9')
  holes++;
```

Arrays have no natural place here, because the array would have to be populated first:

```
String s=String.valueOf(num);
char[] digits=new char[s.length()];
for(int i=0;i<digits.length;i++)
  digts[i]=s.charAt(i);
```

Your code did not work because it had only 1 of these 4 lines, the `new[]`, and the array was left empty (which means full of zeroes).

And then a separate loop would do the checks

```
int holes=0;
for(int i=0;i<digits.length;i++){
  if(digits[i]=='8')
    holes+=2;
  else if(digits[i]=='0' || digits[i]=='6' || digits[i]=='9')
    holes++;
}
```

The result is: same functionality, a bit of wasted memory (the array), and 4-5 extra lines of code to type (again, the array). Strictly said the `String` is wasted memory already, and the array just duplicates it.

Comment: Why do you insist on using an array? It is not needed

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

Your code is creating an array with 4 zeros and then just counting the number of zeros.

A bit more detail:

- You created and initialized `numarr` (to all zeros, which is the default value for `int`s), but didn't override any of the values.
- The length of `numarr` is the length of `num` after it is converted to s String.
- Your loop just ends up counting the number of zeros in `numarr`.

If you really want to use an array in your algorithm, try iterating through an array of `char`s (where each `char` represents a `num` digit):

```
public static void holesinNum(int num){
    int numofholes = 0;
    final char[] numChars = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<numChars.length; i++) {
        final char c = numChars[i];
        if (c=='8') {
            numofholes +=2;
        } else if (c=='0' || c=='6' || c=='9') {
            numofholes++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total holes in int are: " +numofholes);
}
```

Comment: Enter a number: 
6984
Total holes in int are: 4  \n It is not counting zeros it shows me the length of the array.

Comment: Where is the number entered?  But it does not really matter: 'numarr' is always an array of length 'num' in which every element contains zero.  This is observably true because there is no code assigning any values to the elements of 'numarr'.

Comment: I have passed the number from the main function. Just normal use if Scanner and passed. It shows the correct length of array hence the array is not empty

Comment: The array is not empty. It is full of zeroes.  ```numarr[i]``` is zero for all ```i```.

Comment: @Learner_me Sure, `6984` has 4 holes. But your code is creating an array with 6984 zeros and then just counting the number of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
int[] numarr = new int[String.valueOf(num).length()];
```

You successfully initialize an array that is the size of your input value, but you never put any numbers in the array.

Generally speaking, the best method of doing this would not involve an array. Assuming you need to use one though, I would go through each character of the String, get the numeric value of the char, and assign it to the respective position in the array. This can easily be done with a for loop.